# Android HPROF file, is there a way to reveal the native memory part?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, heap-memory, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I play with MAT tools and Haha Library which is a hprof file parser.

I can reveal fields of a java object(eg. Bitmap):

[image]

But there is some information I want: `mNativeBitmap` in the screenshot..

I suppose it is a native pointer, is there a good way to reveal the memory block which the pointer point to?

---

As @CommonsWare said: the native heap isn't count in hprof.

Is there a way/guide can help me dump the native memory part which the pointer point to?

I can dump hprof when my app is running, so I think I can analyze the object find the pointer's value, then I dump the memory block with my own native helper library, simple memcpy stuff?

Can I dump the native memory block without writing a native library?

Comment: AFAIK, native memory information is not captured. After all, that memory block could be measured in GB, since native allocations do not need to honor the process' heap limit.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank your for the tips! I wonder if there is a way I can dump the native heap and hprof heap at the same time?